# Calling RPC success from another RPC success

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

I have done a rpc in my code. On the success side, i have some code as trigger to this rpc call.

I have a second rpc in my code. On the success side of this another call, I want to execute the code that is in the first rpc success side.

Without copying the code that is into the first rpc success, is it any way to call this first successful rpc code from the second rpc success?.

Thank you in advance for your time,

Kind regards,

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, either put your interesting code in a separate method, e.g.

```java
service.doX(..., new AsyncCallback<String> {
  void onSuccess(String str) {
    awesomeness(...);
  } 
});

service.doY(..., new AsyncCallback<String> {
  void onSuccess(String str) {
    awesomeness(...);
  } 
});

void awesomeness(...) {
  // magic stuff
}
```

Or re-use the AsyncCallback:

```java
final AsyncCallback<String> sweetCallback = new AsyncCallback<String> {
  void onSuccess(String str) {
    // magic stuff
  } 
}

service.doX(..., sweetCallback);

service.doY(..., new AsyncCallback<String> {
  void onSuccess(String str) {

    if (whatever)
      sweetCallback.onSuccess(str);
  } 
}
```

(Please note, that the code samples are schematic, and missing e.g. the onFailure methods)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response and for the time taken answering it. This is what i was looking for and therefore missing. Yes, i understand that the code samples are schematic but very explainable by themselves. :)

Kind regards,